# Object returns null when comeback from one viewController to another in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using two view controllers: `RegisterViewController` and `Exp`.

`RegisterViewController` includes an IBOutlet button and this button's value is set when loading the view for the first time. But i need to change button image from another view controller (`Exp`).

How can I do this ?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIButton *but;
-(void)Image:(UIImage*)img;
@end

@implementation RegisterViewController
@synthesize but;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"but :%@",self.but);//<UIButton: 0xa581ed0; frame = (119 270; 62 62); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa581b50>>
}


-(void)Image:(UIImage*)img
{
    NSLog(@"but:%@",self.but);// returns null Value
    [self.profileBut setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];//I can’t change image by this line.What is the problem?
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RegisterViewController.h"

@interface Exp : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong)RegisterViewController *regCont;
@end

@implementation Exp
@synthesize regCont;

-(void)dissmissView
{
    self.regCont = [[RegisterViewController alloc]init];
    [regCont Image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cute_cat_1.jpg"]];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create new object for `RegisterViewController ` but, use the same instance which was created before.Or You need to implimate delegate.

Comment: yes It is obvious because if your view in not on the screen IBOutlets   doesn't refers any UIComponents. You can set Image in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear

Comment: @prashant how to access my RegisterViewController method from Exp?

Comment: yon can access `RegisterViewController ` from your navigation stack by using array of VCS `[self.navigationController viewcontrollers]'

Comment: @prashant how to access instance method in 'RegisterViewController' from 'Exp'

Comment: Iterating through array and you can check `isKindOfClass` is `[RegisterViewController class]` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Well the simple thing you can do is use `NSNotificationCenter`. So just add observer in firstOneViewController and post the same in another ViewController. And inside the FirstViewController of notification method, just set the image of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the delegation between these two controller

your `RegisterViewController` will define a protocol and a delegate object like

```
@protocol RegisterViewControllerDelegate

-(void)chageImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

then define a delegate property and then your `ExpViewController` will implement your delegate and this method will change your image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set other view's controller outlets properties until the view controller is loaded. Instead you should declare a property of NSString in RegisterViewController and set it from Exp and then on RegisterViewController's viewDidLoad, fetch that NSString property's value and create UIImage out of it and set it as background image on RegisterViewController's profileBut  button.

Answer (score 0):

try this  ....

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation RegisterViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"but :%@",self.but);//<UIButton: 0xa581ed0; frame = (119 270; 62 62); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa581b50>>

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
        name:@"TestNotification"
        object:nil];
}

implement selector method 

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
      if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
      {
          [self Image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cute_cat_1.jpg"]];
      }
}
```

in Exp viewController

```
@implemenration Exp : UIViewController

-(void)dissmissView
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:self];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```